# Azure SSL Cert on Web App

Tags: azure, ssl-certificate

I've purchased an SSL cert in the Azure Portal that I want to use in a Web App.

When I go to the **Web App** -> **Custom Domains & SSL** -> **Import Certificate** it lists the cert that I have purchased. When I select the cert it says that it has successfully added the certificate to the App.

The problem is that the certificate never appears in the Apps SSL Bindings. I select the host name, yet no certificates appear in the certificate dropdown to choose from.

Hoping someone has some insights!

Comment: Does the host name you specified match the common name (CN) for the certificate?  These must be the same for the portal to offer it as a valid configuration.

Comment: Yes Rick the name did match. It looks like it was an issue with the portal that resolved itself in the end. Thanks.